# SQL Server CE rollback does not undo delete

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server CE 3.5 and C# with the .NET Compact Framework 3.5. In my code I am inserting a row, then starting a transaction, then deleting that row from a table, and then doing a rollback on that transaction. But this does not undo the deletion. Why not? Here is my code:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = ConnectionSingleton.Instance;
conn.Open();
UsersTable table = new UsersTable();
table.DeleteAll();
MessageBox.Show("user count in beginning after delete: " + table.CountAll());
table.Insert(
new User(){Id = 0, IsManager = true, Pwd = "1234", Username = "Me"});
MessageBox.Show("user count after insert: " + table.CountAll());
SqlCeTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
table.DeleteAll();
transaction.Rollback();
transaction.Dispose();
MessageBox.Show("user count after rollback delete all: " + table.CountAll());
```

The messages indicate that everything works as expected until the very end where the table has a count of 0 indicating the rollback did not undo the deletion.

Comment: If DeleteAll is doing a truncate, that's your problem right there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just got it answered on Microsoft's forum. You need to associate the SqlCeComand object with the transaction using the SqlCeCommand object's Transaction property.

Comment: Correct - transactions on the connection are not automatically enlisted by all commands being run against that connection.  You have to tell the command to participate in the transaction.